# Can I turn off highlighting of TODO keywords?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using several normal verbs as TODO keywords. For example, 'Fix' is a TODO keyword, and when it gets done it turns into 'Fixed'. This works well except I find the highlighting distracting. Can I turn it off? Ideally I would like a task to be a simple sentence "Fix ..." with no special highlighting, but recognised as a todo item.

TODO keywords have the org-todo face by default, but changing this face doesn't do the trick. It reinstates the default if I turn off one of the attributes, and in any case the foreground should match the current level, so there is no one colour that would work. If It's org-level-x I want it to look like org-level-x.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on [Emacs Stack Exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could break/modify the function `org-get-todo-face`, which is used by `org-set-font-lock-defaults`.  Or, if you comment out `(list (format org-heading-keyword-regexp-format org-todo-regexp) '(2 (org-get-todo-face 2) t))` within `org-set-font-lock-defaults`, then the keyword will take on the color of the title of the task.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably try to study some more elisp and modify one of these two. Just commenting out (list (format org-heading-keyword-regexp-format org-todo-regexp) '(2 (org-get-todo-face 2) t)) works for active todo's but it breaks todos that are done: the rest of the line has the org-headline-done face, but the done keyword doesn't.